# Generically rewriting Scala case classes

Tags: scala, reflection, case-class, shapeless

Is it possible to generically replace arguments in a case class?  More specifically, say I wanted a substitute function that received a "find" case class and a "replace" case class (like the left and right sides of a grammar rule) as well as a target case class, and the function would return a new case class with arguments of the find case class replaced with the replace case class?  The function could also simply take a case class (Product?) and a function to be applied to all arguments/products of the case class.

Obviously, given a specific case class, I could use unapply and apply -- but what's the best/easiest/etc way to generically (given any case class) write this sort of function?

I'm wondering if there is a good solution using Scala 2.10 reflection features or Iso.hlist from shapeless.

For example, what I really want to be able to do is, given classes like the following...

```
class Op[T]
case class From(x:Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]
case class To(x:Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]

case class Target(a:Op[Int], b:Op[Int]) extends ...
// and lots of other similar case classes
```

... have a function that can take an arbitrary case class and return a copy of it with any elements of type From replaced with instances of type To.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you'll pardon the plug, I think you'll find that the rewriting component of our [Kiama language processing library](http://kiama.googlecode.com) is perfect for this kind of purpose. It provides a very powerful form of strategic programming.

Here is a complete solution that rewrites `To`'s to `From`'s in a tree made from case class instances.

```
import org.kiama.rewriting.Rewriter

class Op[T]
case class Leaf (i : Int) extends Op[Int]
case class From (x : Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]
case class To (x : Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]

case class Target1 (a : Op[Int], b : Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]
case class Target2 (c : Op[Int]) extends Op[Int]

object Main extends Rewriter {

    def main (args : Array[String]) {
        val replaceFromsWithTos =
            everywhere {
                rule {
                    case From (x) => To (x)
                }
            }

        val t1 = Target1 (From (Leaf (1)), To (Leaf (2)))
        val t2 = Target2 (Target1 (From (Leaf (3)), Target2 (From (Leaf (4)))))

        println (rewrite (replaceFromsWithTos) (t1))
        println (rewrite (replaceFromsWithTos) (t2))
    }

}
```

The output is

```
Target1(To(Leaf(1)),To(Leaf(2)))
Target2(Target1(To(Leaf(3)),Target2(To(Leaf(4)))))
```

The idea of the `replaceFromsWithTos` value is that the `rule` construct lifts a partial function to be able to operate on any kind of value. In this case the partial function is only defined at `From` nodes, replacing them with `To` nodes. The `everywhere` combinator says "apply my argument to all nodes in the tree, leaving unchanged places where the argument does not apply.

Much more can be done than this kind of simple rewrite. See [the main Kiama rewriting documentation](https://code.google.com/p/kiama/wiki/Rewriting) for the gory detail, including links to some more examples.

Comment: !!!  What!  Yes!  Your library is exactly what I want.   My case classes are in fact a tree of operations on which I want to do a series of optimizations.

Comment: Sweet! Let me know how you get on. Happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you'll really find a better way than just using unapply/apply through pattern matching:

```
someValue match {
  case FindCaseClass(a, b, c) => ReplaceCaseClass(a, b, c)
  // . . .
}
```

You have to write out the rules to associate `FindCaseClass` with `ReplaceCaseClass` somehow, and although you might be able to do it a little more succinctly by somehow just using the names, this has the added benefit of also checking the number and types of the case class fields at compile time to make sure everything matches just right.

There is probably some way to do this automatically using the fact that all case classes extend [`Product`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Product.html), but the fact that `productElement(n)` returns `Any` might make it a bit of a pain—I think that's where reflection would have to come in. Here's a little something to get you started:

```
case class From(i: Int, s: String, xs: Seq[Nothing])
case class To(i: Int, s: String, xs: Seq[Nothing])

val iter = From(5,"x",Nil).productIterator
val f = To.curried
iter.foldLeft(f: Any) { _.asInstanceOf[Any => Any](_) }
// res0: Any = To(5,x,List())
```

But really, I think you're better off with the pattern-matching version.

***Edit:*** Here is a version with the relavent code refactored into a method:

```
case class From(i: Int, s: String, xs: Seq[Nothing])
case class To(i: Int, s: String, xs: Seq[Nothing])

type Curryable = { def curried: _ => _ }

def recase(from: Product, to: Curryable) = {
  val iter = from.productIterator
  val f = to.curried
  iter.foldLeft(f: Any) { _.asInstanceOf[Any => Any](_) }
}

recase(From(5,"x",Nil), To)
// res0: Any = To(5,x,List())
```

Comment: The issue here is that I want a function that can accept *any* case class and replace any productElements of type From with productElements of type To (To is a subtype of From).  I'm not concerned as much as about how to build a To from the From class -- the question is how to generically copy a the target case class.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @Josh - You really don't see how the Product code can work with any pair of case classes? Regardless, it looks like the solution mhs suggests using HLists is probably the way you want to go.

Comment: I was trying to draw the target case class (in which I want to replace the From to To) into the question.  But actually your solution is the most immediately practical.  Edit your answer slightly so I can change my vote on your answer?

Comment: Actually, this doesn't get all the way there -- how do you generically apply the curried method?  There's a bunch of reflection to be done.

Comment: @Josh - Did you try it? I think the type erasure that's happening allows you to apply the function without reflection—but if the types don't actually work you might get a nasty runtime error. The other issue with my code is that it returns type Any, but you should be able to fix that with a cast and some more generic arguments.

Comment: OK, yeah, this can be done with reflection with something like: y.getClass.getMethods().filter( _.getName == "copy").headOption.map(_.invoke(y, y._1.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]))

Comment: @Josh - I think you missed the point... The code in my answer is already doing that, but without reflection. You can also make it work more generically without needing explicit reflection—but I still haven't figured out a way to make it give you back a nice return type rather than `Any`. I'll post a version with the code refactored to use a method.

Comment: What version of scala are you using for that final example?  It won't compile for me.  But your new example is very helpful in that shows a general function abstracted from the specific classes.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still using 2.9.2, not 2.10. It's very possible that they've changed stuff in the type system so this doesn't quite right anymore. Scala isn't exactly known for its backward compatibility...

Answer (score 4):

I experimented a bit with shapeless and was able to come up with the following, relatively generic way of converting one case class into another:

```
import shapeless._ /* shapeless 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT */

case class From(s: String, i: Int)
case class To(s: String, i: Int)

implicit def fromIso = Iso.hlist(From.apply _, From.unapply _)
implicit def toIso = Iso.hlist(To.apply _, To.unapply _)

implicit def convert[A, B, L <: HList]
                   (a: A)
                   (implicit srcIso: Iso[A, L],
                             dstIso: Iso[B, L])
                   : B =
  dstIso.from(srcIso.to(a))

val f1 = From("Hi", 7)
val t1 = convert(f1)(fromIso, toIso)

println("f1 = " + f1) // From("Hi", 7)
println("t1 = " + t1) // To("Hi", 7)
```

However, I was not able to get the implicits right. Ideally,

```
val t1: To = f1
```

would be sufficient, or maybe

```
val t1 = convert(f1)
```

Another nice improvement would be to get rid of the need of having to explicitly declare iso-implicits (`fromIso`, `toIso`) for each case class.

Comment: This seems promising -- I added a clarifying example to make it clear where I'm trying to end up.

Comment: Apparently once a bug with implicit macros is resolved (2.10.1?) adding the implicit defs could be done with a macro, which would be great.

Comment: @Josh It would be great if you could illustrate how you would do it with macros. A link to a gist maybe.