# Scala 2.10: Dynamically instantiating case classes

Tags: scala, reflection, types

I have a dream of "dynamically instantiating case classes" -- and providing some dummy data for the fields depending on each fields type (I'll create some rules for that later)

So far I have some code which works with case classes with `String`; `Long` or `Int` ... and am a bit stuck on if its possible to handle embedded case classes

So I can instantiate `case class RequiredAPIResponse (stringValue: String, longValue: Long, intVlaue: Int)`

but not Outer; where Outer is ...

```
case class Inner (deep: String)
case class Outer (in : Inner)
```

The code is

```
 def fill[T <: Object]()(implicit mf: ClassTag[T]) : T = {

      val declaredConstructors = mf.runtimeClass.getDeclaredConstructors
      if (declaredConstructors.length != 1)
      Logger.error(/*T.toString + */" has " + declaredConstructors.length + " constructors --- only 1 currently supported.")
      val constructor = declaredConstructors.headOption.get

      val m = constructor.getParameterTypes.map(p => {
          Logger.info("getName " + p.getName +" --- getCanonicalName " + p.getCanonicalName)
          Logger.info(p.getCanonicalName)

        p.getCanonicalName match {
          case "java.lang.String" => /*"Name"->*/ val s : java.lang.String = "DEFAULT STRING"
            s
          case "long" => /*"Name"-> */ val l : java.lang.Long = new java.lang.Long(99)
            l
          case "int" => /*"Name"->*/ val i : java.lang.Integer = new java.lang.Integer(99)
            i
          case _ => /*"Name"->*/

            So around here I am stuck!
        //THIS IS MADE UP :) But I want to get the "Type" and recursively call fill     
            //fill[p # Type] <- not real scala code

            //I can get it to work in a hard coded manner
            //fill[Inner]

        }
      })
```

I feel like the last answer on [Scala: How to invoke method with type parameter and manifest without knowing the type at compile time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18895341/scala-how-to-invoke-method-with-type-parameter-and-manifest-without-knowing-the) is a starting point for an answer.
So instead of using T <: Object; fill should take ClassTag or a TypeTag?

This code started from - [How can I transform a Map to a case class in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6181845/how-can-i-transform-a-map-to-a-case-class-in-scala) - which mentions (as the Lift-Framework does) I do have the liftweb source code; but so far have been unsuccessful in untangling all its secrets.

EDIT --- Based on Imm's points I've got the below code to work (some minor updates to his answer)

```
def fillInner(cls: Class[_]) : Object = {
    val declaredConstructors = cls.getDeclaredConstructors
    if (declaredConstructors.length != 1)
      Logger.error(/*T.toString + */ " has " + declaredConstructors.length + " constructors --- only 1 currently supported.")
    val constructor = declaredConstructors.headOption.get

    val m = constructor.getParameterTypes.map(p => {
      Logger.info("getName " + p.getName + " --- getCanonicalName " + p.getCanonicalName)
      Logger.info(p.getCanonicalName)

      p.getCanonicalName match {
        case "java.lang.String" => /*"Name"->*/ val s: java.lang.String = "DEFAULT STRING"
          s
        case "long" => /*"Name"-> */ val l: java.lang.Long = new java.lang.Long(99)
          l
        case "int" => /*"Name"->*/ val i: java.lang.Integer = new java.lang.Integer(99)
          i
        case _ => fillInner(p)
      }

    })

    constructor.newInstance(m: _*).asInstanceOf[Object]

  }

    def fill[T](implicit mf: ClassTag[T]) : T = fillInner(mf.runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
```

Thanks,
Brent

Comment: Probably ScalaTest or ScalaCheck has something like this working for automatic test case generation. Shapeless certainly an option (and from the answers it seems Kiama might also be): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13402378/generically-rewriting-scala-case-classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not actually using the `ClassTag`, just the `Class[_]`, and none of this is typesafe (it's just Java reflection), so just pass the `Class[_]` recursively:

```
def fillInner(cls: Class[_]) : Any = {
  val declaredConstructors = cls.getDeclaredConstructors
  if (declaredConstructors.length != 1)
  Logger.error(/*T.toString + */" has " + declaredConstructors.length + " constructors --- only 1 currently supported.")
  val constructor = declaredConstructors.headOption.get

  val m = constructor.getParameterTypes.map(p => {
      Logger.info("getName " + p.getName +" --- getCanonicalName " + p.getCanonicalName)
      Logger.info(p.getCanonicalName)

    p.getCanonicalName match {
      case "java.lang.String" => /*"Name"->*/ val s : java.lang.String = "DEFAULT STRING"
        s
      case "long" => /*"Name"-> */ val l : java.lang.Long = new java.lang.Long(99)
        l
      case "int" => /*"Name"->*/ val i : java.lang.Integer = new java.lang.Integer(99)
        i
      case _ => fillInner(p)
    }
  })

def fill[T: ClassTag]: T = fillInner(classOf[T].runtimeClass).asInstanceOf[T]
```

But you can probably accomplish what you want to do in a typesafe way, perhaps by using Shapeless:

```
trait Supplier[T] {
  def supply: T
}
object Supplier[T] {
  implicit val intSupplier = new Supplier[Int] {
    def supply = 99
  }
  implicit val stringSupplier = ...
  implicit val emptyHListSupplier = new Supplier[HNil] {
    def supply = HNil
  }
  implicit def consHListSupplier[H, T <: HList](
    implicit headSupplier: Supplier[H], 
      tailSupplier: Supplier[T]) = new Supplier[H :: T] {
    def supply = headSupplier.supply :: tailSupplier.supply
   }
}
```

Then by the magic of implicit resolution you can obtain a `Supplier[(String :: HNil) :: Int :: HNil]` or so on for any recursive `HList` of `HList`s that ultimately only contains values for which you've got `Supplier`s; you just need a little more shapeless (different in version 1 or 2, and it's been a while since I've done it, so I don't remember the specifics) to convert back and forth between those and case classes.

Comment: Brilliant thanks - your points about not needing ClassTag in fillInner got me through! I'll take a look a shapeless once my brain stops feeling so mushy

Answer (score 0):

If you only use it in tests, the best way is to use Scala/Java reflection.

The advantage over using Macros is that it compiles faster. The advantage over using scalacheck-related libraries are that the API is nicer.

Setting it up is a bit involved. Here is a full working code that you can copy into your codebase:

```
import scala.reflect.api
import scala.reflect.api.{TypeCreator, Universe}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

object Maker {
  val mirror = runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)

  var makerRunNumber = 1

  def apply[T: TypeTag]: T = {
    val method = typeOf[T].companion.decl(TermName("apply")).asMethod
    val params = method.paramLists.head
    val args = params.map { param =>
      makerRunNumber += 1
      param.info match {
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Enumeration#Value] => chooseEnumValue(convert(t).asInstanceOf[TypeTag[_ <: Enumeration]])
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Int] => makerRunNumber
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Long] => makerRunNumber
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Date] => new Date(Time.now.inMillis)
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Option[_]] => None
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] && param.name.decodedName.toString.toLowerCase.contains("email") => s"random-$arbitrary@give.asia"
        case t if t =:= typeOf[String] => s"arbitrary-$makerRunNumber"
        case t if t =:= typeOf[Boolean] => false
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Seq[_]] => List.empty
        case t if t <:< typeOf[Map[_, _]] => Map.empty
        // Add more special cases here.
        case t if isCaseClass(t) => apply(convert(t))
        case t => throw new Exception(s"Maker doesn't support generating $t")
      }
    }

    val obj = mirror.reflectModule(typeOf[T].typeSymbol.companion.asModule).instance
    mirror.reflect(obj).reflectMethod(method)(args:_*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }

  def chooseEnumValue[E <: Enumeration: TypeTag]: E#Value = {
    val parentType = typeOf[E].asInstanceOf[TypeRef].pre
    val valuesMethod = parentType.baseType(typeOf[Enumeration].typeSymbol).decl(TermName("values")).asMethod
    val obj = mirror.reflectModule(parentType.termSymbol.asModule).instance

    mirror.reflect(obj).reflectMethod(valuesMethod)().asInstanceOf[E#ValueSet].head
  }

  def convert(tpe: Type): TypeTag[_] = {
    TypeTag.apply(
      runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader),
      new TypeCreator {
        override def apply[U <: Universe with Singleton](m: api.Mirror[U]) = {
          tpe.asInstanceOf[U # Type]
        }
      }
    )
  }

  def isCaseClass(t: Type) = {
    t.companion.decls.exists(_.name.decodedName.toString == "apply") &&
      t.decls.exists(_.name.decodedName.toString == "copy")
  }
}
```

And, when you want to use it, you can call:

```
val user = Maker[User]
val user2 = Maker[User].copy(email = "someemail@email.com")
```

The code above generates arbitrary and unique values. They aren't exactly randomised. The API is very nice. It's best for using in tests considering that it uses reflection.

Read our full blog post here: https://give.engineering/2018/08/24/instantiate-case-class-with-arbitrary-value.html